# MySQL: Naming scalar-valued subqueries in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query with a where cluse like that:

`WHERE (scalar-subquery1) > (scalar-subquery2)`

And it works fine. There can be any operator here instead of "greater than" (">") between queries.

Now I want to give a names for these queries so that I can reference them in select clause, so I tried:

`SELECT q1,q2 ... WHERE (scalar-subquery1) as q1 > (scalar-subquery2) as q2`

But there is syntax error reported between `as q1` and `>` operator. Any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as a subquery:

```
select q1, q2
from (select (scalar-subquery1) as q1, (scalar-subquery2) as q2
     ) t
where q1 < q2
```

Or as a cross join:

```
select q1.val, q2.val
from(scalar-subquery1) as q1 cross join
    (scalar-subquery2) q2
where q1.val < q2.val
```

The third option is a variant of the first:

```
select t.*
from (select <current select>
             (scalar-subquery1) as q1, (scalar-subquery2) as q2
      from <current from>
     ) t
where q1 < q2
```

Comment: Unfortunately these are correlated subqueries that depend on other table from FROM clause. If I put these queries to FROM clause, I'm getting errors about unknown column, because a table declared in from is not visible for these queries now.

Comment: I'm not a fan of correlated subqueries.  However, the third option should do what you want.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk: Your scalar subquery in WHERE is also a correlated one if it depends upon tables in the FROM clause. It doesn't matter whether you put in SELECT or WHERE if you still need to evaluate it against every row that your FROM clause produces.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want:

```
SELECT (scalar-subquery1) as q1, (scalar-subquery2) as q2 ... WHERE (scalar-subquery1) > (scalar-subquery2)
```

I don't think MySql allows you to reference items in the where clause from the SELECT

Comment: So I need to repeat both subqueries twice? Really isn't there a way to  reference a subquery from where in select or other way around (from select in where)?

Comment: Not as far as I know - but then again I usually work with Sql Server not MySql so I'm no guru :)